# django-plotly-dash argument in template

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I need to send initial data from my template to my dash script. I found demo of it [here](https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/blob/master/demo/demo/templates/demo_two.html) looks like this:

```
{</span>% plotly_app name="simpleexample-1" initial_arguments='{"dropdown-color": {"value": "green"}}' %}
```

I need to do the same and do it like this:

```
{% plotly_app name="SimpleExample" initial_arguments='{"id": {"value": "2"}}' %}
```

but how i get in my dash script? (Id should be like variable (i need to use this in all project) )